# Add constraints in Max-flow

Tags: java, algorithm, max-flow, operations-research

I'm trying to find *k*(k is given) path using Max-flow from source node s to destination node t with some constraints in graph G= (V, E). Given Different subsets A_i of V, One subset can have one or more than one nodes. **Problem is i can use one subset only in one path**. I'm using this code [Finding max-flow](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-max-flow-min-cut-theorem/)

How can i add each subset only can use one path in this code (i mean if i use subset A_1 in path 1 then i can't use A_1 again for other paths ? I'm new in java. I tried to upload my problem picture but i couldn't because i'm new for this side.
Thanks

Comment: One "pragmatic" approach could be: When a flow uses a vertex from subset A1, then simply remove all vertices of A1 from V before computing the next flow....

Comment: @Marco13 Right now that sounds like a bad idea to me because you can't know in advance that the path you picked is in some maximal flow.

Comment: I'm agree with @G. Bach. But how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do the edges in G all have capacity 1 or are the capacities arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, all capacity 1 and A_i is not necessarily connected.